# Retrieving a column based on FK - three tables

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq

Newbie C#/.Net coder here. I am trying to create a view displaying columns from three different tables. One of the columns is retrieved using a foreign key.

The CategoryDetailViewModel contains a list of Services and a list of Providers.
The Services table contains a ProviderId as well as a CategoryId.
I am able to retrieve the service name related to the category fine.
My question is how can I retrieve the provider name?
My CategoriesController looks like this, sans the question marks which indicate my lack of knowledge.
I need another join or subquery to make this work - just don't know how to do it in Linq. :'(

```
    public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {

        Category theCategory = context.Categories
            .Include(c => c.Services)
            .Include(c => c.Providers)
            .Single(c => c.Id == id)
            .Single(c => c.Services.ProviderId == );



        CategoryDetailViewModel viewModel = new CategoryDetailViewModel(theCategory);
        return View(viewModel);     
    }
```

Comment: Why two `Single`? How it ever compiles?

Comment: Did I mention I was a newbie to C#/.Net and Linq?  ;^)
It does not yet compile as I am struggling to code this query.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example of Join, then match your example with it

```
var p = context.Categories
          .Join(context.Services,
               left => left.Id,
               right => right.CategoryID,
               (left,right) => new { categories = left, services = right })
          .Join(context.Providers,
               left => left.services.Id,
               right => right.ProviderId,
               (left,right) => new { categories = left.categories, services = left.services , providers = right})
          .Where(c => c.services.ProviderId == id);
```

Comment: Thank you @Meysam Asadi, I will attempt with this guidance. :)

Comment: Almost. I am getting an error on services and Services. 

CS1061 - 'anonymous type Category categories, Service services, Provider providers' does not contain a definition for 'Services' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'anonymous type Category categories, Service services, Provider providers' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Will try to add a screenshot.
Suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to enter your table structure or related classes?